# Rotate border of a line

Tags: html, css, web, rotation

[image]

I need some help as I am very new to coding. I am trying to design a website with a Website Builder (Homepage Baukasten) and I had to rotate a line through code as you can see on the image. The problem is now that I don't know how to transform its border (the white horizontal square) so I can place it where its supposed to go. I looked around to found a way but I did not found anything that did the job.

Thank you for your time and have a nice one!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You seem to have a weird value in your style attribute. Please look at for example  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style for the correct syntax. In particular a style= within a style= makes no sense.